# Which compound or compounds are responsible for color change in blue butterfly pea flower tea?

Tags: ph, food-chemistry, color

[Blue Butterfly Pea flower tea](https://www.bonappetit.com/drinks/non-alcoholic/article/butterfly-pea-flower-color-changing-tea) is blue by default. Add citrus juice and it turns purple. What compound or compounds are responsible for this reaction to change in pH?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitoria_ternatea) doesn't say, nor can I find any source on the internet that does.

Comment: Many pH indicators (all, actually) do similar colour changes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_cabbage#pH_indicator is a well known example. What did you do during chemistry lessons in school? ;-)

Comment: @Karl - Yes. Which pH indicator(s) is in the tea?

Comment: I don't know what's the blue stuff in *Clitoria Ternatea*. Some biologist might be able to find out. Is it important for you? The colour change surely comes from one of the typical reactions that occur in pH indicators.

Comment: @Karl. I'm simply curious. I hope that's a good enough reason to post the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, that was simple. This

https://www.google.de/search?q=Clitoria+Ternatea+blue+color

gave this

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14568080

which lead me to this

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthocyanidin

and I guess that's the culprit. I judge from that abstract linked above that the actual plant can contain a wide mixture of those anthocyanidines.

Comment: I guess my internet research chops need work :-/  Thanks.

Comment: Another interesting article that also mentions this class of compounds in the context of potential anti-inflammatory uses: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jafc.5b00928?src=recsys&journalCode=jafcau

Comment: So it is the same group of chemicals as in red cabbage. Interestingly if you get red cabbage juice on eggs they go blue, so I guess that's the inverse reaction to lemon in blue pea.